# Magento 2: total order amount on the administrator screen does not match with the actual total order amount

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, orders

The total amount "$2.79" displayed in the order list on the backend customer page does not match the actual total amount "$305.29".

That is, the total amount displayed in the list is not equal to the total amount displayed on the order.

No solution found for this problem.
Could you help me?

Below is a list of customer orders.
The price is wrong.
[image]

The diagram below shows what the customer ordered.
The price is right.

[image]

The following image shows the values in the grand _ total and base _ grand _ total columns of the sales _ order table that have display problems.

[image]

Comment: clear the cache run the reindec command and check

Comment: All indexes and caches have been updated. The problem has not been resolved.

Comment: what value in sales_order table for grand_total and base_grand_total for this order

Comment: I added a question. I have added the grand _ total and base _ grand _ total of the orders with display problems. Could you check it?